# Rails image not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, localhost

I've tried searching up my issue but non of the solutions worked. I am super confused why my .png isn't showing when I run my website on localhost:3000.

This is my files structure/folders and src path for robot.png
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hw3w2.png)

Comment: Seeing the code you use to do this would help

Answer (score 1):

You should move all images in `app/assets/images` then use `<%= asset_path 'image_name.png' %>`

This is standard solution

Comment: Thanks for the answer however it didn't fix my problem. page shows now : `/assets/robot-21929452ab382079d8f9c28763539584774757a809a84f9d4d6e0dff016e83a8.png` instead of actual png

Comment: ```<img src="<%= asset_path 'image_name.png' %>">``` or ```<%= image_tag "image_name.png" %>```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<%= image_tag ("images/robot.png") %>
```

`image_tag` will automatically add assets at start of the path

Take a look at [Image Tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag) for documentation.

Comment: Thanks ! unfortunatelly I am getting `The asset "images/robot.png" is not present in the asset pipeline.` Very annoying since I know that png is there...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up saving it in new directory assets/images/logos/robot.png and using `<%= image_tag ("logos/robot.png") %>` and it finally worked !